# Using jQuery to store the state of a complicated form

Tags: jquery, forms, session-state

I have a rather complicated form with many "steps" in it that are filled in by the user. Some steps (think of them as form segments) have default options, but on clicking a "enter custom values," they display a hereto hidden set of fields that the user can enter info in. Here is an example

```
<div id="#s1_normal">
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="a"> Mode A
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="b"> Mode B
Choose one of the above for applying average coefficient 
values of "a" or "b" to 100% of your product or
<a href="#" onclick="toggleCustom('s1');">enter custom values</a>
</div>

<div id="#s1_custom">
%a: <input type="text" name="perc_a"> coeff. a <input type="text" name="coeff_a">
%b: <input type="text" name="perc_b"> coeff. b <input type="text" name="coeff_b">
Enter custom values above or 
<a href="#" onclick="toggleCustom('s1');">choose average values</a>
```

There are several such segments, for example, #s1 .. #s7. Here is my task. I want to enable the user to save the state of a form. So, once a user has filled out the entire form, choosing average defaults for some segments, and entering custom values for other, the user is able to click a button and have the entire state saved for thawing later. I am thinking, if I can save the state in an object that I can serialize, I can save it in a db table or some other persistent storage.

The user can come back at a later time and re-construct the entire previous session.

How do I do this? There is the getAttributes plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes, and there is the jQuery serialize method, but I can't for the life of me get started. Please nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 25):

Here are a couple functions to help with this process. `formToString` serializes a form as a string, and `stringToForm` does the reverse:

```
function formToString(filledForm) {
    formObject = new Object
    filledForm.find("input, select, textarea").each(function() {
        if (this.id) {
            elem = $(this);
            if (elem.attr("type") == 'checkbox' || elem.attr("type") == 'radio') {
                formObject[this.id] = elem.attr("checked");
            } else {
                formObject[this.id] = elem.val();
            }
        }
    });
    formString = JSON.stringify(formObject);
    return formString;
}
function stringToForm(formString, unfilledForm) {
    formObject = JSON.parse(formString);
    unfilledForm.find("input, select, textarea").each(function() {
        if (this.id) {
            id = this.id;
            elem = $(this); 
            if (elem.attr("type") == "checkbox" || elem.attr("type") == "radio" ) {
                elem.attr("checked", formObject[id]);
            } else {
                elem.val(formObject[id]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
// Convert form to string
var formString = formToString($("#myForm"));
// Save string somewhere, e.g. localStorage
// ...

// Restore form from string
stringToForm(formString, $("#myForm"));
```

Comment: This is so useful! Just a note for those who don't know how to call the function, I used it like this: `sessionStorage.setItem("formdata",formToString(jQuery("#form")));`, and then this to call it: `var storedform = sessionStorage.getItem("formdata");
        stringToForm(storedform,jQuery("#form"));`

Comment: Is the `$j(this)` expression a typo? I am getting JavaScript errors when using this script, and assume it should be `$(this)`, right?

Comment: It wasn't a typo, but I removed it from the answer, since just `$` is the default way of accessing jquery. See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/ for more info

Comment: You forgot `textarea`

Comment: @HDog added `textarea`, how's that?

Comment: in `stringToForm` you do `stringForm.find()` and loop over the results.  inside the loop you also do `stringForm.find()` on the found element's id.  this will always find the current item so it is not necessary to find the same element twice.  `var input = $(this)` is simpler

Comment: @JulianK hello sir and thank you - would you be able to elaborate on sessionStorage. In my particular case, a user is directed away from a form, and is then brought back to it, obviously when returned i don't want the user to click the same drop down menu every single time - which would be annoying to get through. any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: if checked="checked" in HTML and you click the box, then attr("checked") still == "checked"

Comment: should use formObject[this.id] = elem.prop("checked"); to make it work. (jQuery 2.2.0)

Comment: @JulianK - on which browser events do you setItem and getItem() ?
I'm clear that setItem() is probably done in form.onsubmit(), but getItem() - I tried putting it in BodeyOnload(), but this seems wrong because this is executed both on back button as well as when the page arrives from the server. The goal is to restore the form only On Back Button action

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using the [dumbFormState jQuery plugin](https://github.com/sebringj/jquery.dumbformstate).

That plugin actually automatically saves things while you are typing etc. so when they come back, its already filled out again and you don't need server-side to do it.

After that, I would create further jQuery to load after the dumbFormState plugin to then show/hide the areas that are filled out. Its no problem if you call this before someone ever filled out their form because it will be blank and your logic should not show/hide things that are blank anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), which serializes `form data`. To do that, your `input` elements need to be within a `form tag` plus, all of them have to have `name` attributes.

```
var form1data = $('#form1').serialize();

alert(form1data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As I noted in my question, I am aware of the serialize method, however, that, to me, seems like only a part of the solution. To restore the form, I have to read the stored serialized data, and then reconstruct the form back to the state, including all its custom entries.. that is, if a hidden segment was unhidden to enter custom values, I want to bring that back. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @punkish: I'm not aware of some `deserialize()` method in the jQuery core. So you either have to code your own custom parser or look for a plugin.

Comment: @punkish here's my [formstate plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/mindplay/yLPY3/) - an alternative to serialize() and the missing unserialize() that works with objects rather than strings; I wanted a lightweight plugin that only deals with form-state, not with string-representations or storage-methods. It handles radios, checkboxes, etc. in a sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just put the data that is non-default into a json, then send it through a post request to the server to be saved.

So, once the person goes back to the page you automatically look to see if they have something saved, and you can either ask if they want to use it or populate the form from the saved data.

Saving default values is a waste of bandwidth, as you won't be changing it from what the form was when it was loaded anyway.

**UPDATE:**

To save it as a JSON I think it would be easy enough to just build it up into a long string since the format is easy, so you will just send everything as a single string.

You may want to also save the stage they are on, or, automatically save as they go to each stage, which may be a better option, in case their computer crashes they won't have to start at the beginning again, but you may want that enabled by a checkbox, to turn on auto-save.