# Rails collapse nested form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic, form-for

Does anyone have any idea/resources for how to create a form in Rails that can use either bootstraps "Collapse" or Jqueries "Accordion" functionality?

Basically, I have a huge form with many nested attributes, and I would like to collapse them so that a user only has to open the section he or she wants to edit. I have to believe that there has to be SOMETHING like this out there, but all I've seen are unanswered questions from people attempting to integrate bootstrap or jquery with either formtastic or form_for.

Basically, I'm looking for something that can integrate with rails and that looks similar to this: http://www.alpacajs.org/examples/forms/customer-profile/edit-form.html

UPDATE:

Sorry, I just realized that my original post might be a bit vague. I AM attempting to use Formtastic (or rails form_for) DSL, and have that integrate with the collapse functionality. I just really haven't seen anywhere on the web where people have been successful at putting these together.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it simple and have more control over what you are including in your app you can easily achieved the effect you need with a few lines of javascript.

I've put an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/iKindred/pYgLY/2/

And here's the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.collapsable-section').each(function(i){
        var $label = $(this).find('.label').filter(':first');
        var $fields = $(this).find('.fields').filter(':first');
        $label.click(function(e){
            $fields.slideToggle(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Feel free to tailor it to your needs or let me know if you need help :)

Comment: sir, i've noted when I press the back button on the browser the collapse trick fails to work - perhaps due to some caching. do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: To achieve that you need to persist the state of the form whenever there is a change (using local storage or something), and recall that state when the form loads again.

Comment: thank you - i searched and found this which others might find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432614/using-jquery-to-store-the-state-of-a-complicated-form

Answer (score 0):

I use [bootstrap sass gem](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass). In Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  # ...
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  # ...
end
```

You have to add to `application.js.coffee` the following line

```
#= require bootstrap-collapse
```

In the view containing your form (for instance `_form.html.erb`, you just have to encapsulate the form tags that you want to collapse as following:

```
<div class="collapse">
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
</div>
```

Comment: hello @toch, I could not get it to work on my form :( - do you have any examples which you've managed to get working?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon it was in 2013, but I guess the current solution should be the same more or less. What are the versions you're working with?

Comment: i'm using rails 4 - it's been so long that i've forgotten i posted the original comment. perhaps don't worry about it unless someone else posts a comment?