# How to reload current page without losing any form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Can I reload current page without losing any form data? I used..

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

and

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

But these two things can't get earlier form datas for me. What is wrong ? When refresh browser manually, it is fine (I don't lose any form data).  Please guide me how to figure it out.

Here is my full code...

```
<div class="form-actions">
        <form>
            <table cellpadding = "5" cellspacing ="10">
                <tr class="control-group">
                    <td style="width: 100px;">
                        <div>Name:&nbsp;<font color="red">(*)</font></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="control-group">
                    <td>
                        <div>Email:&nbsp;<font color="red">(*)</font></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="span3" placeholder="user@gmail.com" id= "inputEmail" type="email" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="control-group">
                    <td>
                        <div>Phone:&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="inputPhone" placeholder="phone number">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="control-group">
                    <td>
                        <div>Subject:&nbsp;<font color="red">(*)</font></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="control-group">
                    <td colspan ="2">
                        <div>
                            <div>Detail:&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <textarea id="inputDetail"></textarea>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <div>
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;" class="checkbox"> <input id="confirmCheck" value="" type="checkbox">
                                I Agree to the Personal information handling policy
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div id = "alert_placeholder"></div>
                        <div class="acceptment">
                            [Personal information handling policy]<br> <br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div align="center">
                            <button id="btnConfirm" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
                            <input type="reset" style="width: 65px; height: 27px;" id="btnReset" class="btn">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And at my JS file..

```
function bind() {
$('#btnConfirm').click(function(e) {
    if ($('#confirmCheck').is(":checked")) {
        getConfirmationForSendFAQ();
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
        showalert("You should accept \"Personal Information Policy\" !", "alert-error");
    }
});};function getConfirmationForSendFAQ() {
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
    var phone = $('#inputPhone').val();
    var subject = $('#inputSubject').val();
    var detail = $('#inputDetail').val();

    $('.form-actions').empty();
    html = [];
    html.push("<table cellpadding ='8' class = 'submitInfo'");
    html.push("<tr>");
    html.push("<td class = 'title'>Name:</div>");
    html.push("<td class = 'value'>"+ name +"</td>");
    html.push("</tr>");

    html.push("<tr>");
    html.push("<td class = 'title'>Email Address:</div>");
    html.push("<td class = 'value'>"+ email +"</td>");
    html.push("</tr>");

    if (phone.trim().length > 0) {
        html.push("<tr>");
        html.push("<td class = 'title'>Phone No:</div>");
        html.push("<td class = 'value'>"+ phone +"</td>");
        html.push("</tr>");
    }

    html.push("<tr>");
    html.push("<td class = 'title'>Subject:</div>");
    html.push("<td class = 'value'>"+ subject +"</td>");
    html.push("</tr>");

    html.push("<tr>");
    html.push("<td class = 'title'>Detail Info:</div>");
    html.push("<td class = 'value'>"+ detail +"</td>");
    html.push("</tr>");

    html.push("<tr>");
    html.push("<td colspan='2'><div align = 'center'>");
    html.push("<button id='btnSend' class='btn btn-primary' style='width: 65px;'>Send</button>");
    html.push("<button id='btnReturn' class='btn btn-inverse' style='width: 65px; height: 27px; margin-left: 5px;'>Return</button>");
    html.push("</div></td></tr>");

    html.push("</table>");
    $('.form-actions').append(html.join(''));
    $('#btnReturn').click(function(e) {
        // HERE I WANT TO KNOW HOW TO DO.....
    });
    $('#btnSend').click(function(e) {
        alert("Doom");
    });}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use various local storage mechanisms to store this data in the browser such as the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) and WebSQL (deprecated) (and UserData with IE).

The simplest and most widely supported is Web Storage where you have persistent storage ([`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) or session based ([`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)) which is in memory until you close the browser. Both share the same API.

You can for example (simplified) do something like this when the page is about to reload:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("name", $('#inputName').val());
    localStorage.setItem("email", $('#inputEmail').val());
    localStorage.setItem("phone", $('#inputPhone').val());
    localStorage.setItem("subject", $('#inputSubject').val());
    localStorage.setItem("detail", $('#inputDetail').val());
    // ...
}
```

Web Storage works synchronously so this *may* work here. Optionally you can store the data for each blur event on the elements where the data is entered.

At page load you can check:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val("name");

    // ...
}
```

`getItem` returns `null` if the data does not exist.

Replace "`localStorage`" with "`sessionStorage`" in the code above if you want to store data only temporary.

Comment: @Cataclysm if the intention is to go back to the form you can probably use `history.go(-1);` instead?

Comment: @ Ken - Abdias Software history.go(-1); or history.back(); These will redirect previous page. Not previous , I want to reload current page and I had tested with that bro! thanks...

Comment: This works for me thanks a lot. But I need correct your answer: 
1) localStorage.setItem('name', ...
2) if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val('name');
=> Without quotes this solution not work for me. I correct it via official guide on WebStorage.

Comment: One thing I don't like about this: How do you know when to clear the storage? First idea is to clear on form submit, but let's say data gets committed to storage then user decides they don't want to submit this data. Now they are permanently stuck in a broken state until their localStorage is cleared (or the form submits)

Comment: I have 100 input (5 form on same page) do we have a option to get it done without setting it every input @k3n

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta you can use a literal object, then stringify it via JSON (parse() to get it back to object)

Comment: @JLewkovich - you can have an event listener on the form field to detect when its content changes. When it changes, you can update the LocalStorage.

Comment: Wonderful. Just one issue: ...val("name"); for me only works without the quotes. Otherwise I get the string "name".

Comment: What if I'm editing the same page in multiple tabs?

Comment: Any chance you can help me with a code sample to a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73499526/how-can-i-keep-the-check-boxes-checked-after-refresh?noredirect=1#comment129795463_73499526

Answer (score 28):

I modified K3N's code to work for my purpose, and I added some comments to help others figure out how sessionStorage works.

```
<script>
    // Run on page load
    window.onload = function() {

        // If sessionStorage is storing default values (ex. name), exit the function and do not restore data
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('name') == "name") {
            return;
        }

        // If values are not blank, restore them to the fields
        var name = sessionStorage.getItem('name');
        if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val(name);

        var email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
        if (email !== null) $('#inputEmail').val(email);

        var subject= sessionStorage.getItem('subject');
        if (subject!== null) $('#inputSubject').val(subject);

        var message= sessionStorage.getItem('message');
        if (message!== null) $('#inputMessage').val(message);
    }

    // Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("name", $('#inputName').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("email", $('#inputEmail').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("subject", $('#inputSubject').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("message", $('#inputMessage').val());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Great idea! **N.B.** sessionStorage gets cleared when the session ends, while localStorage is kept indefinitely. Something to consider when thinking about data privacy.

Answer (score 7):

Find this on GitHub. Specially created for it.

https://gist.github.com/zaus/4717416

Comment: i have a similiar problem any chance you can help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73499526/how-can-i-keep-the-check-boxes-checked-after-refresh?noredirect=1#comment129795463_73499526

Answer (score 6):

This answer was extremely helpful to me, and saves the trouble of going through each field manually:

[Using jQuery to store the state of a complicated form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432614/using-jquery-to-store-the-state-of-a-complicated-form)

Answer (score 6):

```
window.location.reload() // without passing true as argument
```

works for me.

Comment: With IE this does not keep the field values of the page. Since I am experiencing this issue right now, I am looking into [Julian K's link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24223857/1016343) which looks promising to save the values, refresh and then restore them. Local Storage solutions might work as well, although some firm policies prohibit its use for data privacy reasons.

Comment: Works like a charm on Chrome

Answer (score 4):

As some answers mention, [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a good option and you can certainly do it yourself, but if you're looking for a polished option, there is already a project on GitHub that does this called [garlic.js](http://garlicjs.org).

Answer (score 3):

I usually submit automatically my own form to the server and reload the page with filled arguments. Replace the placeholder arguments with the params your server received.

Answer (score 3):

A simple and generic (no jquery) solution for all input (type text) fields unsing the local storage.

```
function save_data(){
    let fields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")
    let saved_fields = []
    fields.forEach(x => {
        saved_fields.push({
            key: x.id,
            value: x.value
        })
    })
    localStorage.setItem("saved_data", JSON.stringify(saved_fields))
 }

 function show_saved_data(){
     JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saved_data")).forEach(x => {
         document.getElementById(x.key).value = x.value
     })
 }
```

if you want to include "select/checkboxes" fields etc. you would have to add some if else logic in the for loop and change the query....

Answer (score 2):

You have to submit data and reload page (server side render form with data), just reloading will not preserve data. It is just your browser might be caching form data on manual refresh (not same across browsers).

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage ( http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp ) to save values before refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with HTML5 LocaStorage.
[This is example code](https://snipt.net/dikkini/html5-local-storage/)

Comment: wow ! great. Thanks for guiding with example for localstorage. But I prefer sessionStorage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library I wrote, [FormPersistence.js](https://github.com/FThompson/FormPersistence.js) which handles form (de)serialization by saving values to local/session storage. This approach is similar to [that linked in another answer](https://gist.github.com/zaus/4717416) but it does not require jQuery and does not save plaintext passwords to web storage.

```
let myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
FormPersistence.persist(myForm, true)
```

The optional second parameter of each `FormPersistence` function defines whether to use local storage (`false`) or session storage (`true`). In your case, session storage is likely more appropriate.

The form data by default will be cleared from storage upon submission, unless you pass `false` as the third parameter. If you have special value handling functions (such as inserting an element) then you can pass those as the fourth parameter. See the repository for complete documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use $_POST itself:

```
<?php           
isset($_POST['value']) ? $value= $_POST['value'] : $value= NULL;
echo '<form method="POST">';
echo '<input type="text" name="value" value="'.$value.'"/>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Register an event listener for `keyup` event:

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  var someVarName = input.value;
  sessionStorage.setItem("someVarKey", someVarName);
  input.value = sessionStorage.getItem("someVarKey");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of very complex solutions but there is a 1 line of code answer. This is a javascript command.

```
history.go(0);
```