# Refresh page with html button, except

Tags: html, button, refresh

How can I implement a "website-refresh-button" which does NOT refresh text input-panels?

**Refresh-Button:**

```
<input name="Button" class="button" type="button" size="20" maxlength="20" value="Load..." onClick="history.go(0)">
```

**Text input-panels:**

```
<input name="StartDate" class="inputPanel" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="2013-08-20">
<input name="StartTime" class="inputPanel" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="22:56:25">
<input name="EndDate" class="inputPanel" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="2013-08-22">
<input name="EndTime" class="inputPanel" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="22:56:26">
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to 'refresh' then?  In order to preserve the values on a proper refresh, you will have to persist them somehow. This can be done in browsers with local storage or cookies or similar.. But it's important to ask what you are aiming to achieve by forcing a refresh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data

Comment: Check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data

This will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve the values on a proper refresh, you will have to persist them somehow. This can be done in browsers with local storage or cookies or similar.

See this SO post for more info:
[How to reload current page without losing any form data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers. I've noticed something. Maybe I don't need the refresh button... Is it possible to refresh the page if I change the value of one inputPanel? Something like "onChange" instead of "onClick"?

Comment: Yes this is possible, but I would recommend a button, or something else 'clickable', to make it more of a conscious choice from the user that they are happy to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already gave a `name` to all the `input`s, I would simply change the button `input`'s type to a `submit`, and put it all inside a form with `method="post" action="#"`. Then, once it's submitted, you take all the items in the POST (server-side) and put them into the `input`s before giving the user the end HTML. If you have no access to the backend server, then ne1410s's solution is your best fit.