# How to not repeat an array in math.random?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

So I have this javascript code, where I want it to not repeat the different r_text's, so the same line of text from r_text[] is not repeated when you refresh the site. Question is, what should the code be?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "All the leaves are brown";
r_text[1] = "And the sky is grey";
r_text[2] = "I've been for a walk";
r_text[3] = "On a winter's day";
r_text[4] = "Id be safe and warm";
r_text[5] = "If I was in L.A.";
r_text[6] = "California dreaming, On such a winter's day";
var i = Math.floor(7*Math.random())

document.write(r_text[i]);

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, so your saying that it will randomly choose a element and write it to the screen. And when you refresh it should not be the element that was on the previous screen before the refresh? Is it just the last element or every element before?

Comment: After 7 refreshes, something will have to repeat. Do you want to simply cycle through the texts in some fixed order on a 7-refresh cycle?

Comment: If you're looking to persist data on a refresh, this post may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591919/1496080 Save some indicator of what has/has not been picked yet. When you have none left, clear that persisted data.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Right now when you click refresh on the site with this code it will some times repeat the same text as has been shown before you refreshed. 

Is there a way to do it, so for instance I don't get "Ive been for a walk" two times in a row after refreshing, or better yet; doesnt ever get the same again after you've loaded the site one time?

Comment: I realize now that it only repeats and can have this issue after the 7th time. This solves my problem. Thanks and sorry for the confusion :) - an easy question for anyone out there, but how do I add a Hyperlink in one of the r_text[]'s so it also can add a hyperlink sometimes? 


So how would I be writing a URL inside this: 
    the r_text[5] = "HOW DO I PUT IT IN HERE?"