# Back button which goes back to filled in form

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add a Back button which reloads  a form with the inputs filled in?

I have a form with some input fields and a save (submit) button. When clicking submit, if the mandatory fields aren't filled in, a new page opens with a message. If I use the browser's Back button, I receive this message:

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be
>   properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you
>   will repeat any action this page previously performed. Press the
>   reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
>   ERR_CACHE_MISS

So basically, it asks me to Refresh, and then confirm by clicking OK on a pop up window, after which the form reloads but with empty fields.

I have tried thinking of everything, but I can't find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say with no code or specific technology you're using. The general architectural ways to solve this is to not navigate away from the form page at all until the data is correct. But what works for you is impossible to say with no details.

Comment: How are you saving the fields that are already filled in?  You're probably going to have to use webstorage as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591919/4976543 ... Then, you could easily fill in the fields with an onload function on the page..

Comment: Additionally, cookies are an option: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible, I would change the structure so that the form posts back to itself, and runs the validation of the mandatory fields. Then, if everything's ok, it will continue whatever processing is necessary. If there's a problem, it can show the form again, but in your code you will have access to the values already submitted, so you can pre-populate the form with these values and then display it to the user. It's a pretty standard design technique for this sort of thing.

Comment: I did something similar, using sessions, and it works:`//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];` . Page 2 is the same as Page 1, only with the input fields already field in as the last time.

Comment: I guess that will work, but then you are duplicating the code for your form, which has a big disadvantage because it makes it more difficult to change it in future (you have to change everything twice).