# How to retain a value of dropdown using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit, cascadingdropdown

I have a three dropdown with 1 submit button. Now, I'm trying to retain the value of each dropdown after the user clicked the input submit. But the Jquery I have is not working. I use PHP to displayed the output of the dropdown when the user clicked it.

**Note:** The page is refresh when the user clicked the input submit.

How to fix this? See in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TkjwRYbdFUIgrCM2UINi)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').change(function(){
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $('#dropdown').val(option);
    });

});
```

Comment: All that does is set the value of the select to the value the user just selected. Are you trying to persist the value across a page refresh?

Comment: @Actorclavilis, yes. When the input submit clicked by the user, the page will reload and the values of dropdown is not retaining

Comment: do you have any code written in your button click event ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa, i don't have since, I use the `<input type="submit">` and  i displayed the output of submitted form using PHP

Comment: Ok then check my answer below. You can call that function however depending on your application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload current page without losing any form data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values easily by making use of the `model` attribute present in the `select` element.

First add a onclick function like so

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getValues()"/>
```

Then get the value on submit of the button(**Entire code**) [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/t88ATGahi5RK0qaPFZkB?p=preview)

I had a look at your code, the way your selectbox rendering is setup we have to explicitly call the `updateSelect()` function for the options to work well. This function makes your selectbox "dynamic".

```
var first = localStorage.getItem("firstDropDown");
var second = localStorage.getItem("secondDropDown");
var third = localStorage.getItem("thirdDropDown");

if(first !== null && second !== null && third !== null) {
  setValues(); //this should come after getting  the values above
}

function getValues() {
  var first = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].getAttribute("model");
  var second = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[1].getAttribute("model");
  var third = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[2].getAttribute("model");

  localStorage.setItem("firstDropDown", first);
  localStorage.setItem("secondDropDown", second);
  localStorage.setItem("thirdDropDown", third);
}

//on load when this function is called globally, the values from the localStorage will be set to the dropdown values.
function setValues() {
  //for first dropdown
  document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].setAttribute("model", first); 
  document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].value = first;
  updateSelect(document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0]);
  //for second dropdown
  document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[1].setAttribute("model", second);
  document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[1].value = second;
  updateSelect(document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[1]);
  //for third dropdown
  document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[2].setAttribute("model", third);
  document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[2].value = third;
  updateSelect(document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[1]);
}
```

To retain the value you have no choice but to use a `window.localStorage` like so -

```
localStorage.setItem("firstDropDown", first);
localStorage.setItem("secondDropDown", second);
localStorage.setItem("thirdDropDown", third);
```

Then fetch the value

```
var first = localStorage.getItem("firstDropDown");
var second = localStorage.getItem("secondDropDown");
var third = localStorage.getItem("thirdDropDown");
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but still the values is not retain

Comment: you want after the page refreshes ?

Comment: yes, after the user click the input submit (the page automatically refresh after submit)

Comment: check my updated answer. This should do what you expected.

Comment: in `firstDropDown`, should i change? should i place the id of select? If that so, I only have 1 id in 3 select box.

Comment: No no don't worry, the `firstDropDown` is just the name of the local storage variable that we have given. it can be anything(make sure it has a different name then the other storage variables though)

Comment: did you use the "entire code" that I updated above. Note: the `localStorage.setItem` should be inside the button click function and `localStorage.getItem` should be outside it. Also you can `console.log` the `first`, `second` & `third` variables & tell me whats the value after refresh

Comment: If you open the "Chrome Debugger", choose the **Application** tab, then under **Storage** > **Local Storage** what do you see ?

Comment: Yes, i copied the entire code. I check the console.log and the values are displayed

Comment: So now you can use those values where you want to. So that's what you wanted right ? Check this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/t88ATGahi5RK0qaPFZkB?p=preview). You will get `null` the first time since you have nothing stored now choose the dropdowns and submit & reload the page, you should see what you had chosen earlier

Comment: but when i click the submit button, the values is not retain in the 3 dropdown

Comment: Awww ok, now I know what exactly you want. Just one more step then, working on it.

Comment: which select box library are you using here ?

Comment: what do you mean select box library? I'm just using native JS

Comment: I got it.. Updated the answer.

Comment: Can you check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123438/discussion-between-user014019-and-nikhil-nanjappa).

Comment: @User014019 - Since you got your answer, you can mark the answer as accepted & help others as well in the future.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for late reply, I tested your updated code in my side and I noticed that the 3rd updateSelect(document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[1]); the array number is 1 instead of 2, right? but when I tried to change it to 2 the 3rd dropdown value is not retained.

Comment: Yes that's right, it is supposed to be 2 instead of 1. I updated the Plunkr in my answer, there it seems to be working fine for me. Check the plunkr & let me know if your problem still persists. I can help you out if not. Its almost done anyways. FYI: try running your app after clearing your browser's localStorage

Answer (score 2):

Use local storage with all option;

```
$("#dropdown").change(function(){

      var html=$("#dropdown").html();
      localStorage.setItem("myapp-selectval",html);

      localStorage.setItem("myapp-selectvalselected",$("#dropdown").val());              //to retain selected value
})
```

Now on document load;

```
window.onload=function()
{
    if(localStorage.getItem("myapp-selectval")!="" && localStorage.getItem("myapp-selectval")!=undefined)
    {
        $("#dropdown").html(localStorage.getItem("myapp-selectval"));

        $("#dropdown").val(localStorage.getItem("myapp-selectvalselected"));                 //to get previously selected value
    }
}
```

Once again as I said in comment it's not a good solution.

Comment: the first dropdown values is missing

Comment: Now whats the issue? You have to keep the "$("#dropdown").change(function(){" code  inside window.onload.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is going to refresh the page, your best bet is to have the server send down the value that the user just submitted with the new page load.

If that's impossible for some reason, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var prevVal = localStorage.getItem('selectValue');
    prevVal && $('#dropdown').val(prevVal);

    $('#dropdown').change(function(){
        var option = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem('selectValue', option);
    });

});
```

Keep in mind that not all browsers support this API yet.

**EDIT**: If you don't need the browser to refresh, you can use Ajax:

```
// ...
$('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var option = $('#dropdown').val();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('dropdown', option);
    $.ajax('/path/to/form/target/', {
        method: 'POST',
        formData: fd
    });
    // ...
});
//...
```

Comment: The user is not manually refresh the browser but when the user click the `input type="submit`, the page is automatically refresh

Comment: It should not matter how they refresh the browser.

Comment: what is `selectValue`?

Comment: looks like `selectValue` is just a key in localStorage.It's basically key-value database. You can use any key you want but if you will have more it's good idea to make a naming convention for them.

Comment: i tried your code, but only the 1st dropdown is retain

Comment: You can use sessionStorage also. But using these is not a good way as there may be another web application that is using same key(selectValue) to store any value. In that case that value 'll  override.  So if you somehow wants to use it select a key uniquely like yourAppName-selectval or something like that.

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL: I'm pretty sure that `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` is scoped to the domain. That said, you're right that it's a less clean solution than the others.

Comment: @Actorclavilis you are right. I really didn't notice it before. It's is scoped to the domain. Thanks man. New knowledge gained. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I assume OP's question asks for a JS solution, I do want to bring something else to the table because I was also searching to solve the same problem. However, I ended up solving it in a manner that I considered to be satisfying.

In my case I'm using Flask as the backend, but I believe the solution should be at least similar for other use cases.

On the HTML where the dropdown is located, I pass a variable from the backend which is originally set to be some default value of my choice. Let's call this variable <kbd>default_var_set_in_backend</kbd>. This will ultimately be fed to the HTML and will look like as follows:

```html
<select name="some_name_you_want" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option selected="selected">{{ default_var_set_in_backend }}</option>
```

Once a change is made in the dropdown value by the user (in my case it's a GET request), I update the variable <kbd>default_var_set_in_backend</kbd> to be equal to this new choice. Now, the HTML will reflect the latest choice made by the user once the page refreshes.