# Lose data on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve what may look like a simple task but it is totally confusing me.

When the user clicks a menu item the page refreshes and the user ends up on another page.

A div gets updated with an updated text.

The problem I have is that when the page is refreshed I lose the message "You are on a new page", how do I keep the updated message on the new page?

jquery -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("li.sub-level").click(function (e) {
            $('.mylink').html("You are on a new page");

        });

    });

</script>
```

html -

```
<div class="mylink">My link</div>
```

Comment: You need to persist it - either locally in Local/SessionStorage, the url, or a server.

Comment: yep what I was going to say, localstorage is your best bet https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: javacript is manipulating the DOM after render. That means that the browser will always read the original HTML-file. What you are doing is manipulating the structure after the page is rendered. You need to save that change somehow, like with localStorage

Answer (score 1):

You need to first "save" your first location in the infoObj, I suggest you do it with the url of the first page. 
This will prevent the string "You are on a new page" when you are on the first page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var infoObj = {};
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (localStorage.myLink != null) {
      infoObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.myLink)
      if (infoObj.url == url) {
        $('.mylink').html(infoObj.text);
      }
    }

    $("li.sub-level").click(function(e) {
      infoObj = {
        url: "PUT YOU FIRST PAGE URL HERE",
        text: "You are on a new page"
      }
      localStorage.myLink = JSON.stringify(infoObj)
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Zorken, this doesnt work, I am seeing "You are on a new page" when the page loads, I only want to see this when I click a menu item that refreshes the page $("li.sub-level")

Comment: See my updated code. You must somehow check if you are on the first page or not.

Comment: I had to abandon this approach and instead I am manipulating the page by injecting a url, many thanks to everyone who posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should visit this link. i hope you will get your answer.

Link is here [Demo Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data)

**Or user this below code. how sessionStorage works.**

```
<script>
    // Run on page load
    window.onload = function() {

        // If sessionStorage is storing default values (ex. name), exit the function and do not restore data
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('name') == "name") {
            return;
        }

        // If values are not blank, restore them to the fields
        var name = sessionStorage.getItem('name');
        if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val(name);

        var email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
        if (email !== null) $('#inputEmail').val(email);

        var subject= sessionStorage.getItem('subject');
        if (subject!== null) $('#inputSubject').val(subject);

        var message= sessionStorage.getItem('message');
        if (message!== null) $('#inputMessage').val(message);
    }

    // Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("name", $('#inputName').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("email", $('#inputEmail').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("subject", $('#inputSubject').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("message", $('#inputMessage').val());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why should he use sessionStorage insted of localStorage?

Comment: `sessionStorage` is ephemeral and items disappear whenever the browser tab is closed. This allows you to be more flexible in terms of what you display to the user, based on their browsing session.

Comment: @MD Aman - If you use the `onbeforeunload` event, you may experience trouble with these types of operations as whenever the browser is navigating from page to page, it stops JavaScript execution so your items might not get saved.