# How to refill form data after user refresh without showing the blank controls while reload starts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently to restore value filled by user we are using localstorage. When user inputs any value into the textbox, we save that value in localstorage by:

```
localStorage.setItem("city", JSON.stringify({"cityId":id,"cityName":value}));
```

To restore this value on page load, we are doing:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var cityInfo = localStorage.getItem("city");
    if (cityInfo !== null) {
        var json = JSON.parse(cityInfo )
        $("#cityId").val(json.cityName);
        $("#cityName").attr(id, json.cityId);
    }
}
```

There are few problems here:

- Minor problem: This solution would work only with web browsers that support localstorage.
- Major problem: After user refreshes the page, this value is restored after onload event, this takes too much time.

Comment: did you already try this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591919/5192105

Comment: Localstorage is the only local persistent storage option there is, and typically using a database would be slower for this purpose. 

You could try putting your localstorage retrieval as a script at the top of your document, rather than wrapping it in an onload - however, if the form is not loaded into the DOM before it completes the recovery from localstorage, it will fail when trying to populate.