# Hold form selection after refresh page

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi

I am working on a home automation project with my Raspberry Pi and i have this piece of code running in my php file:

```
<form action="schedule.php" method="POST" name="theForm" id="theForm">
        <select form="theForm" name="selectedPage">
            <option value="">Select Day</option>
            <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
            <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
            <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
            <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
            <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Load day" />
    </form>
```

After a day is selected the page refreshes,  after the refresh the selection is returned to default. Is there a way to "remember" the selection of the user?

Comment: Its php right ? Aren't you storing form values somewhere ? if not you can save that data in localstorage as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data)

Comment: I assume the form posts back to itself (i.e. this code is held within schedule.php)? If so, then when it posts back, you can write PHP to inject the POST values back into the HTML in order to set the selected values, text etc..

Comment: This is not in the php section. After that i use this:
$requested_page = $_POST['selectedPage'];
to get the selection.

Comment: @Chris - you could make use of browser `localStorage` api introduced in html5, are you using JQuery?

Comment: No and i am new to all these so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script could look something like this in order to achieve this:

```
<?php
  $selectedPage = "";
  //get the value the user chose, if the form has been posted back
  if (isset($_POST["selectedPage"]) $selectedPage = $_POST["selectedPage"];
?>
<form action="schedule.php" method="POST" name="theForm" id="theForm">
 <select form="theForm" name="selectedPage">
   <option value="" <?php echo ($selectedPage == "" ? "selected" : "")?>>Select Day</option>
   <option value="Monday" <?php echo ($selectedPage == "Monday" ? "selected" : "")?>>Monday</option>
   <option value="Tuesday" <?php echo ($selectedPage == "Tuesday" ? "selected" : "")?>>Tuesday</option>
   <option value="Wednesday" <?php echo ($selectedPage == "Wednesday" ? "selected" : "")?>>Wednesday</option>
   <option value="Thursday" <?php echo ($selectedPage == "Thursday" ? "selected" : "")?>>Thursday</option>
   <option value="Friday" <?php echo ($selectedPage == "Friday" ? "selected" : "")?>>Friday</option>
   <option value="Saturday" <?php echo ($selectedPage == "Saturday" ? "selected" : "")?>>Saturday</option>
   <option value="Sunday" <?php echo ($selectedPage == "Sunday" ? "selected" : "")?>>Sunday</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Load day" />
</form>
```

P.S. You could make this quite a bit less verbose if you were to, say generate the "option" tags via a loop, based on an array of possible values.