# Javascript onkeyup event

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript's onkeyup event to display date after a user types in content in a form field.

The date displays properly but on page refresh, the date disappears.

How can I retain that date on my view after page refresh and after browser is closed?

Here is my view form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('advance', 'Advance') }}
    {{ Form::text('advance', $worker->advance , array('class' => 'form-control',   'placeholder' => 'None', 'id' => 'advance', 'onkeyup=displayDate()')) }}

     <strong><p style="margin-top: 10px">Advance issued on : </p>
     </strong><p style="margin-top: 20px" id="date"></p>
 </div>
```

Here is my javascript function that displays the date:

```
<script>
        function displayDate() {
            var x = document.getElementById("advance");
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = Date();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You need some kind of storage to keep your data in and use it to re-populate the form on page refresh. This possible duplicate of [**How to reload current page without losing any form data?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data) should have the answer.

Comment: you can use cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cookies

You can save your data in a cookie, read it on page load and fill up your form fields accordingly.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I am very new to javascript; should my displayDate function come below the getCookie function?

Comment: @Martin I've updated the function so now the order of functions won't matter

Comment: What should I replace name, value and days with?(Kindly bear with me, my javascript knowledge is limited) I have placed my function at the top..

Comment: @Martin just replace name with your form date field ( for easier understanding ) and value with the date the user has selected. For now, you can ignore days parameter. Eg: save like `createCookie('dateOfBirth', '2017-05-09')`  and read using `var savedDate = readCookie('dateOfBirth'); document.getElementById('your_field_id').value = savedDate;`

Comment: The user does not select a date, the date displays onkeyup event. I am using laravel, so should I use the updated_at field from my database?

Comment: @Martin oh you should have mentioned that earlier. If you are using laravel,  you can simply send the updated_at date as a parameter to your view and handle ( display )it there. This won't require javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I figure out that later. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Martin Cool, you can mark this as your answer if your query is solved :)