# How can I keep a shown div when checkbox is checked after sumbit a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a registration form in which the fields are shown dynamically (after checking the checkbox). And all work fine, but after submit and reload the page then a div has CSS `display:block`.
How can I keep a shown div till the moment when user uncheck the checkbox even when page will be reloaded?

Here is example:

```js
    $("input#checkbox_other_certifications-0").click(function() {
        if($('input#checkbox_other_certifications-0').is(':checked'))
        $(".xde-element-input-text.xde-element-name-other_certifications").show();  // checked
    else
        $(".xde-element-input-text.xde-element-name-other_certifications").hide();  // unchecked
    });
```

```css
.xde-element-input-text.xde-element-name-other_certifications{
  display:none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="checkbox_other_certifications-0"><input type="checkbox" value="Inne" name="checkbox_other_certifications[]" id="checkbox_other_certifications-0"><span class="xde-input-description">Others</span></label>

<div class="xde-element-input-text xde-element-name-other_certifications">
<label class="wpjb-label">Other - what?</label>
<div class="wpjb-field">
<input id="other_certifications" name="other_certifications" type="text">            </div></div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2wfyusdq/)

Thank you and greet.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve], please! <3

Comment: On page reload you have to write server side code! Which platform are you working on?

Comment: I think its only possible through local storage at client. check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591919/6546440

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for yours answers. 
I'm really "fresh" in that case that why I write here.
I work on Wordpress, so all "systems" which are included in this platform.
Rashomon - can I use " local storage" also to show div?