# Want to keep showing old date for date field?

Tags: laravel

I want to have my `date` field remember my old input after reloading or going to next page.

Is there any way I can do this?

I already tried this way !!

```
< input type= " date " id = " to_date " name = " to_date " value = " {{ old ( 'to_date' ) }} " >
```

Comment: you can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in localStorage and while rendering fetch the value from localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to call it from controller when you open/refresh your page like

Controller:

```
$to_date = $request->old('to_date');
return Redirect::to('/page')->withInput();
```

then, try run it again with your view

```
<input type= "date" id ="to_date" name="to_date" value="{{Carbon\Carbon::parse(old('to_date'))->format('Y-m-d')}}">
```

But, if you want to do the simpliest way is using localstorage, so you save the data first in your localstorage before reload page

Answer (score 0):

Input with type `date` will accept in `2018-04-30` this format:

```
<input type= "date" id = "to_date" name = "to_date" value = "{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse(old ( 'to_date' ))->format('Y-m-d') }}">
```