# how should I declare localStorage variable to avoid a Reference Error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I have discovered 'localStorage' with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data) recently and I am using it to keep an user logged in even if he refresh the web page.

when I only had to save the name of the user, I had no errors, but then, I added a 'grd' variable to save and I got this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: grd is not defined"
```

This is how I fetch the data when the page loads :

```
var name = localStorage.getItem(name);
var grade = localStorage.getItem(grd);
if (name !== null){
  this.user = name;
}
if (grade !== null){
  this.userGrade = grade;
}
```

and this is how I save the data :

```
localStorage.setItem(name, '');
localStorage.setItem(grd, '');
```

What should I change/add to clear the Reference error?

I am using vue.js in this project

Comment: If grd is a key, then try adding quotes around that line localStorage.getItem('grd');

Comment: The getItem function need an string. Try this: localStorage.getItem('grd')

Comment: @Dylan thanks, I added quotes on all 'name' and 'grd' and it works, If you can put a quick answer, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the reference error by adding quotes to the variables grd and name like so:

```
var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
var grade = localStorage.getItem('grd');
```

The referenceces are key values and must be passed as a string.