# Keep Page Scroll on parent page when closing the Dialog Child Page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, dialog

I'm currently working on a new dialog box and that is opened by a link in the page and once the Dialog box is closed, it refreshes the Parent page but my question is how can i stay the Parent current scroll on page refresh

Here is the dialog Close code:

```
$("#dialogStatus").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            autoResize: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 450,
            height: 400,
            modal: true,
            position: ['center', 40],
            close: function (event, ui) {
                var sss = $("#Id").val();
                var hNotif = $("#hiddenNotification").val();
                var ddlvalue = $('#NewFilterBy option:selected').val();
                var ddlStat = $('#StatusId option:selected').val();

                var url = window.location.href;
                var newUrl = updateQueryStringParameter(url, "Id", sss, "ddlFilter", ddlvalue, "statusFilter", ddlStat);
                window.location = newUrl;
            }
        });
```

What happens here now is when I close it, it refreshes and the parent stay at scroll stays at Top of the page

Edit: Tried adding the `document.location.reload()` but it loses the parameter once added

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a parameter 'scrollPosition' in your URL String and when your document is loaded scroll down to the position.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   //The function that scroll down
   var positionToScroll ; //You set here your variable from your server variable scrollPosition
   $(window).scrollTop(positionToScrol);


   $("#dialogStatus").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         autoResize: true,
         resizable: false,
         width: 450,
         height: 400,
         modal: true,
         position: ['center', 40],
         close: function (event, ui) {
             var sss = $("#Id").val();
             var hNotif = $("#hiddenNotification").val();
             var ddlvalue = $('#NewFilterBy option:selected').val();
             var ddlStat = $('#StatusId option:selected').val();

             var url = window.location.href;
             var currentScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop(); // The position of  the scroll bar 
             var newUrl = updateQueryStringParameter(url, "Id", sss, "ddlFilter", ddlvalue, "statusFilter", ddlStat,"scrollPosition",currentScrollPosition );
             window.location = newUrl;
         }
      });


});
```

Edit: If you can't SET your JS variable 'positionToScroll' from your server you can use this

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true :  decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
     }
};


var positionToScroll  = getUrlParameter('scrollPosition');
```

Comment: Is it possible not to use URL parameters for getting the current page scroll?

Comment: Yes you can use LocalStorage or SessionStorage, here is an example : You can use the answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data, before reload you can set an attribute in your LocalStorage 'positionToScroll' and when you reload and get your value you can reset the scroll position to avoid an infinite repetition.

 If you don't understand how to do i can edit an example in my previous post :)