# Can I have two buttons in a single JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a form including some user selections such as dropdown, radio button and a file upload option.
Depending on selected value from dropdown and radio button the file upload buttons will be enabled or disabled.

The issue is when I am trying to upload a file to server, my page refreshes and I loose the data selected by user, which I require to submit at the end.[image: JSP Page]

For some reason I cannot use servlet! How can I retain user selected value and get uploaded file name to submit everything at the end?

Comment: Storing the data before refreshing might help.
Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591919/5031209

Comment: provide your JSP code