# How to save clicked checkbox status in html on google sites

Tags: html

I want to have checkboxes that save their status (checked or unchecked) once I refresh the site.

I copied a very basic checkbox code that I found online to the website that I've created for school and now I have checkboxes next to each school subject, but when I refresh the page they default to being unchecked. I assume this is because the data is not stored anywhere.

I'll put images of the page and the basic code below:

[Basic code I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM7yA.png)    lllllllllllllllllll    [Website Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NznMh.png)

Comment: HTML is volatile. It doesn't save data. You need a storage solution for the DOM state, and then you need to _apply_ the state to the page with JavaScript on page load.

Comment: See [How to reload current page without losing any form data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data)

Comment: Please see [ask]. Code doesn't belong in images. Also take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to save the input data, for example in `localstorage`, like this

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']").forEach(element=>{
  // Set the checkbox to the saved state (if any)
  element.checked = localStorage.getItem("checkbox_id_" + element.id) === "true"
  
  // When the checkbox changes, save the changes
  element.addEventListener("input", (event)=>{
    console.log("checkbox_id_" + element.id)
    localStorage.setItem("checkbox_id_" + element.id, element.checked);
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now I know that I really am too dumb to figure this out at the moment. :) Seriously though, thanks for taking the trouble. Maybe I'll be able to decipher this one day and it will be a great help!! ;)